# At what block height may locktimed transactions get included?

Tags: transaction-verification, locktime, block-validity, height

Transactions with outputs whose sequence is smaller than `UINT_MAX` are interpreted as locked until the timestamp or block height specified in `nLockTime` is reached.

Specifically regarding the block height, I read imprecise or disagreeing information on whether a transaction may be included in a block of `height > nLockTime` or `height ≥ nLockTime`. Which of the two is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transaction becomes valid when the chaintip reaches the height specified in the locktime, and may be included in any block with a height **greater** than `nLockTime`.

> ```
>     if ((int64_t)tx.nLockTime < ((int64_t)tx.nLockTime < LOCKTIME_THRESHOLD ? (int64_t)nBlockHeight : nBlockTime))
>     return true;
> ```
>
> via https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.19.0.1/src/consensus/tx_verify.cpp#L21L22

H/T Pieter Wuille for code section and explanation.